# Is Groot usually "Asleep for the danger"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, groot

In *Guardians of the Galaxy*, after rescuing Gamora from being killed, Rocket says the following:

> Asleep for the danger, awake for the money, as per frickin' usual.

Do we know of any other time that Groot has been "asleep for the danger"?

Comment: Do you mean the MCU films or in general?

Comment: @Gallifreyan Preferably MCU, if not general

Comment: All we've got to go on for the MCU is the two movies, and across both of those Groot is asleep all of once, which is just before Rocket says this line. I'm not sure about the comics. Does Groot actually even sleep at all?

Comment: There is the *Guardians* cartoon eh, maybe he sleeps in that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on how you want to interpret the phrase, it could be that Raccoon thinks that Groot doesn't really participate until the money. For example, he was happily drinking out of the fountain instead of looking for jobs during their introduction. "Asleep at the job" includes people zoning out (at least that is what I'm told at meetings.)

Plus, Rocket is kind of abusive in general, so it could have just been a generalization instead of a literal observation.